# Enable disable custom right click menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/CmJ9z/

I have a checkbox that if it's checked I want a custom right click menu, but if it's not to have the default browser's context menu. However as soon as it's unchecked the custom menu still pops up and once checked again it shows/hide/show.

Can someone help explain what I'm doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
if ( $("#tm").prop('checked') === true ) {
    // Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
        // Avoid the real one
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
        // Show contextmenu
        if ($("#showcustom-menu").show() === true) {
            $("#custom-menu").hide(100).
            // In the right position (the mouse)
            css({
                top: event.pageY + "px",
                left: event.pageX + "px"
            });
        } else {
            $("#custom-menu").show(100).
            // In the right position (the mouse)
            css({
                top: event.pageY + "px",
                left: event.pageX + "px"
            });
        }
    });

    // If the document is clicked somewhere
    $(document).bind("mousedown", function () {
        $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
    });

    $("#custom-menu li").click(function(){
        // This is the triggered action name
        switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
                // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions
            case "duplicate": alert("duplicate called"); break;
            case "remove": alert("remove called"); break;
            case "deselect": alert("deselect called"); break;
        }
    });
} else {

}
$("#tm").on('change', function() {
    if ( $(this).prop('checked') === true ) {
        // Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
        $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
            // Avoid the real one
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
            // Show contextmenu
            if ($("#custom-menu").show() === true) {
                $("#custom-menu").hide(100).
                // In the right position (the mouse)
                css({
                    top: event.pageY + "px",
                    left: event.pageX + "px"
                });
            } else {
                $("#custom-menu").show(100).
                // In the right position (the mouse)
                css({
                    top: event.pageY + "px",
                    left: event.pageX + "px"
                });
            }
        });

        // If the document is clicked somewhere
        $(document).bind("mousedown", function () {
            $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
        });

        $("#custom-menu li").click(function(){
            // This is the triggered action name
            switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
                    // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions
                case "duplicate": alert("duplicate called"); break;
                case "remove": alert("remove called"); break;
                case "deselect": alert("deselect called"); break;
            }
        });
    } else {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this: **working demo** =>  http://jsfiddle.net/vLtgk/ `:)`

you need to `unbind` the contextmenu :

- http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Lemme know if I misunderstood anything, but this will fit you needs `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).unbind("contextmenu");
```

**full code**

```
if ( $("#tm").prop('checked') === true ) {
    // Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
        // Avoid the real one
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
        // Show contextmenu
        if ($("#showcustom-menu").show() === true) {
            $("#custom-menu").hide(100).
            // In the right position (the mouse)
            css({
                top: event.pageY + "px",
                left: event.pageX + "px"
            });
        } else {
            $("#custom-menu").show(100).
            // In the right position (the mouse)
            css({
                top: event.pageY + "px",
                left: event.pageX + "px"
            });
        }
    });

    // If the document is clicked somewhere
    $(document).bind("mousedown", function () {
        $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
    });

    $("#custom-menu li").click(function(){
        // This is the triggered action name
        switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
                // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions
            case "duplicate": alert("duplicate called"); break;
            case "remove": alert("remove called"); break;
            case "deselect": alert("deselect called"); break;
        }
    });
} else {
    $(document).unbind("contextmenu");
}
$("#tm").on('change', function() {
    if ( $(this).prop('checked') === true ) {
        // Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
        $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
            // Avoid the real one
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
            // Show contextmenu
            if ($("#custom-menu").show() === true) {
                $("#custom-menu").hide(100).
                // In the right position (the mouse)
                css({
                    top: event.pageY + "px",
                    left: event.pageX + "px"
                });
            } else {
                $("#custom-menu").show(100).
                // In the right position (the mouse)
                css({
                    top: event.pageY + "px",
                    left: event.pageX + "px"
                });
            }
        });

        // If the document is clicked somewhere
        $(document).bind("mousedown", function () {
            $("#custom-menu").hide(100);
        });

        $("#custom-menu li").click(function(){
            // This is the triggered action name
            switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
                    // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions
                case "duplicate": alert("duplicate called"); break;
                case "remove": alert("remove called"); break;
                case "deselect": alert("deselect called"); break;
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(document).unbind("contextmenu");
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't know there was an unbind event handler. This is gonna be handy. Mucho gracias

Comment: @mikethedj4 glad it helped `:)` yeah, handy indeed yo!